# how to calculate the estimated joint probability distribution for the red and green pixels only in a png image?

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have a png image that contains the red and green channels only.  I removed the blue channel from the image for calculation purposes.  I need to calculate the estimated joint probability distribution for these pixels.  I came across this function:
numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov[, size])
but this one computes the known distribution.  I need to calculate the estimated distribution.  Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot.
Areej

Comment: It sounds like you want the 2d histogram of the intensity values. Do you want to fit this histogram with a normal distribution (ie calculate the mean and covariance matrix)?

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for your reply Bago.  I don't know a lot a bout stats.  All I know is that I want the estimated joint probability distribution because it is required for the mutual information calculation.

Answer (score 5):

it's easy to bin the data into a set of histograms

```
#2d histogram gives you the counts, in each cell
(H,redEdges,greedEdges) = numpy.histogram2d(
    red.ravel(),green.ravel(),
    bins=nbins
)

#divide by the total to get the probability of 
#each cell -> the joint distribution
Prg = H/H.sum()

#sum over the `green` axis to get the `red` marginal (nx1)
Pr = H2d.sum(1)[:,numpy.newaxis]
#sum over the `red` axis to get the `green` marginal (1xn) 
Pg = H2d.sum(0)[numpy.newaxis,:]
```

From there the mutual information is easy:

```
#calculate information contribution of each bin
dIrg = Prg*numpy.log(Prg/(Pr*Pg))
#filter nans and sum
Irg = dIrg[~numpy.isnan(dIrg)].mean()
```

Comment: Wow Suki this looks great.  Thanks a lot.  I have not tried it yet but if I try it and still have problems can I e-mail you?

Comment: Hi Suki.  I ran the code but I still have an error at the last line.  This is the error:Warning: divide by zero encountered in log
Warning: invalid value encountered in multiply
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyentlast.py", line 293, in <module>
    test()
  File "pyentlast.py", line 288, in test
    Irg = dIrg(~np.isnan(dIrg)).sum()
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
how do I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Never mind i fixed that error but the final result for mutual information is negative! It should be positive right?

Answer (score 0):

Using scipy, there are a number of distributions you can fit to data.  Here's an example of how to do that, assuming you're loading your image from a .png or .jpg or related file:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import scipy.stats as ss

im = numpy.array(Image.open("myfile.png")
red = im[:,:,0]
green = im[:,:,1]

from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.hist(red.ravel())
pyplot.hist(green.ravel())

# if your data follow a normal distribution
print "red mean: %g  sigma: %g" % ss.norm.fit(red.ravel())
print "green mean: %g  sigma: %g" % ss.norm.fit(green.ravel())
```

If you want a different distribution, replace `norm` above with one of these: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

Comment: hi keflavich.  Thanks a lot for your reply.  I need the joint prob. distribution because it is required for the mutual information calculation:Formally, the mutual information of two discrete random variables X and Y can be defined as:

    I(X;Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x \in X} p(x,y) \log{ \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)} \right) }, \,\! 

where p(x,y) is the joint probability distribution function of X and Y, and p(x) and p(y) are the marginal probability distribution functions of X and Y respectively.  So does that code you gave me generate what I am looking for? thanks

Comment: No, I answered a different question; my solution only gives you the marginal distributions.  This thread asks the same question you did: http://old.nabble.com/pdf-for-multivariate-normal-function--td24625501.html.  Suki's answer gets you the distribution directly from the data.